# java: how to create class that accesses all interface objects

Tags: java, class, methods, interface

i am using Java and i have this hierarchy

```
class Seq

class For extends Seq

interface SeqIt

Class ForIt implements SeqIt
```

And `ForIt` has a constructor:  `public  ForIt( For x ) //takes For objects`

Till now everything works fine.
Now I want to make a new class called `FU` that gets access to any `ForIt` objects I created. 
And this `FU` class must have a method with this signature `public static int sum1(For MyFor)`
For example if ForIt objects have inside it an array called myArr. This method sum1 is supposed to return the sum of all elements of the array myArr inside MyFor object

How can I create this class `FU`?

Comment: What do you mean by access to any `ForIt` object?

Comment: for example, i have in the main an object called r1 declared using the constructor ForIt r1 = new ForIt(new For(3, 8, 2));
and another one ForIt r2 = new ForIt(new For(4, 3, 1));
ok?
so now i want to use the FU class to get the sum of the elements inside the r1 array or the r2 array
int sum= (FU.sum1(r1));
int sum2= (FU.sum1(r2));

Comment: Your question says the `FU` has a method `sum1(For)` but your comment above passes a `ForIt` to `sum1`. Which is correct? Are you passing a `For` or a `ForIt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 ways I can think of are:

- Every time you create a `ForIt` class, add it to your `FU` class - when you are done, call the sum method
- Have the `ForIt` class constructor call a static method of the `FU` class to let it know a new `ForIt` was created

I would personally use option 1 as it avoids static variables which can be a pain to work with. Option 2 would work for a simple use case.

```
//not thread safe
class FU {
    private final List<ForIt> list = new ArrayList<> ();
    private int sum = 0;

    void add(ForIt fi) {
        list.add(fi);
        sum += fi.getValue();
    }

    int sum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Option 1 is fairly straigthforward (create a `FU` object, and every time you create a `ForIt` instance, add it to the `FU` object).
Option 2:

```
class ForIt {
    private static final FU fu = new FU();

    ForIt() {
        fu.add(this);
    }

    static int sum() {
        return fu.sum();
    } 
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    new ForIt();
    new ForIt();
    System.out.println(ForIt.sum());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your description, you can just make ForIt as instance variable in FU class, something like this:

```
public class FU {
    public ForIt forit; // Now you have access to ForIt object

    public static int sum1(For MyFor) {
         // Iterate array in ForIt instance
         FU fu = new FU();
         for (int something: fu.forit.myArr){
                ...........
         }
         ........
    }

}
```

Comment: non-static variable forit cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Just added static keyword. My bad

Comment: i tried this but this gives me access to the For object but not to the ForIt functions [the ForIt is different from For]. is my question clear?

Comment: @user1763553 After second though, yeah I am not sure what you really want. I edited the code so that the ForIt instance variable would work with static sum1() method, if you really want "access to any ForIt object".